# Java s.nextInt(); error message

Tags: java, netbeans, int

i am trying to add a "restaurant" to my system. I keep getting this error message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at 
projects.dao.textdao.TextRestaurantDAO.loadRestaurants(TextRestaurantDAO.java:40)
at projects.ProjectIncrement2.loadRestaurants(ProjectIncrement2.java:83)
at projects.ProjectIncrement2.main(ProjectIncrement2.java:25)
Java Result: 1
```

This is the code it keeps taking me to when I click the error message (the part that says restaurantTables = s.nextInt(); And restaurantSeats = s.nextInt(); ):

```
@Override
public List<Restaurant> loadRestaurants(Path path) {
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = new ArrayList<>();   
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.toString())))) {         
        s.useDelimiter(Character.toString(DELIMITER));
        Restaurant r;
        int restaurantId, restaurantTables, restaurantSeats;
        String restaurantName, restaurantLocation;


        while (s.hasNext()) {
            if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                restaurantId = s.nextInt();
                restaurantTables = s.nextInt();
                restaurantSeats = s.nextInt();
            }
            else {
                restaurantId = 0;
                restaurantTables = 0;
                restaurantSeats = 0;
            }
            restaurantName = s.next();
            restaurantLocation = s.next();
            s.nextLine();
            r = new Restaurant(restaurantId, restaurantName, restaurantLocation, restaurantTables, restaurantSeats);
            restaurants.add(r);
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TextCustomerDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
    return restaurants;
}
```

I am unsure of how to fix this error as anything I try just brings me back to this error. Excuse me if I am looking in the completely wrong place but I am trying.

If someone could point me in the right direction and help me fix this error it would be much appreciated.

Thankyou

*If you require more code then please ask*

Comment: So, if there is one int, you try to read three of them... what if there *aren't* three of them?

Comment: @azurefrog I understand what you mean but how can it be fixed?

Comment: Check `if (s.hasNextInt())` before each `s.nextInt()`.

Comment: which line is line 40?

Comment: You're reading a file, so I would suggest reading a line at a time from your scanner.  You can parse each line into its component data separately.

Comment: Can you add a couple of lines of your file, so that it is easier to give you some help?

Comment: Thankyou @azurefrog for pointing me in the right direction and explaining I have corrected the problem. :)

Comment: And Thankyou @Turing85 for giving me the correct solution.

Comment: @PauloSantos I have a solution but thankyou!